# Update <ion-datetime> control data using formGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a form that is built using 'FormBuilder' and it contains a date control . How can I set (update) data to that control using `patchValue()`?

The control has `displayFormat="DD.MM.YYYY"` set in the template.

Data on all other controls ( and ) is set , but the date control remains empty.

page/component/.ts file

```
userDataForm: FormGroup;
user: UserModel;

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
) {
    this.userDataForm = this.buildForm();
}

buildForm(){
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName: ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required
        ])],
        dateOfBirth: ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required
        ])]
    });
}

ionViewWillEnter() {
    // load data...
    refreshForm();
}

refreshForm(){
    this.userDataForm.patchValue({
        firstName: this.user.firstName,
        dateOfBirth: new Date("2016-04-19T18:03:40.887"), // does not work
    });
}
```

Template:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        <form [formGroup]="userDataForm">

            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>Name: *</ion-label>
                <ion-input formControlName="firstName" type="text"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>Date: *</ion-label>
                <ion-datetime formControlName="dateOfBirth" displayFormat="DD.MM.YYYY"></ion-datetime>
            </ion-item>

        </form>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: ¿ userDataForm.controls['dateOfBirth'].value=new Date(2016-04-19) ?

Comment: @Eliseo value is a read-only property. I tried with `this.userDataForm.get('dateOfBirth').setValue(new Date("2016-04-19T18:03:40.887"));` but still nothing.

Comment: ion-datetime require a "string" or a "Date"? if is a string then you must write this.userDataForm.get('dateOfBirth').setValue("2016-04-19T18:03:40.887")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Eliseo in the comments for leading me to the answer.

`<ion-datetime>` expects a date string, and not a date object so this works:

```
refreshForm(){
    this.userDataForm.patchValue({
        firstName: this.user.firstName,
        dateOfBirth: (new Date("2016-04-19T18:03:40.887")).toJSON(), 
    });
}
```

in my case `user.dateOfBirth` is of type `date` so I use it like this:

```
refreshForm(){
    this.userDataForm.patchValue({
        firstName: this.user.firstName,
        dateOfBirth: this.user.dateOfBirth.toJSON(), 
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey, how about the opposite? When you have to save this "datetime" to datetime type in your server side? How do you convert to date/time format?

Comment: This answer helps me a lot! If you use ngModel on <ion-datetime> for update it will give current time only so remove ngModel and then patch or set value on reactive forms!